# C++ templates reading type from configuration file at runtime

Tags: c++11

I've been trying to write a piece of code that reads a configuration file at runtime, and this file contains the names of different variables, and their type. These types are almost all builtin (int, unsigned int, char*, unsigned long long, float), with the exception of one class which stores information as binary flags.

Example configuration file contains:

*Name std::string Measurement*

*PositionX float 0.004*

*PositionY float 0.002*

*Time unsigned long long 1521479000*

Function which needs this information:

```
std::vector<float> xPos;
...
while( loops_over_a_file_containing_values );
...
xPos.push_back(get_information["PositionX"].extract<float>());
```

However, I cannot for the life of me seem to find a method in which to define these in a C++ code, most of my googling leads me to "This doesn't work" or answers that are so complicated to me that I cannot implement it in a reasonable way.

The main reason behind this is because there are a rather large number of variables with different types, and their type is needed as this function comes from another user written C++ package (which I have no way to modify in any shape or form).

So far I've looked at boost::any, boost::variant but I can't see how this could be done with those. And I'm unsure how exactly to go about this with templates either, I've tried:

```
template <int ModeDecider> class TypeDecider{ };
template <> class TypeDecider<0>{ public: typedef int Type; };
template <> class TypeDecider<1>{ public: typedef unsigned int Type; };
template <> class TypeDecider<2>{ public: typedef unsigned long long Type; };
template <> class TypeDecider<3>{ public: typedef float Type; };

...

std::string test1 = "unsigned long long";
std::string test2 = "1521479000";

switch( test1 ){
...
   std::vector<TypeDecider<2>::Type> testvec;
   testvec.push_back(static_cast<TypeDecider<2>::Type>(test2));
...}
```

But this gives me:

```
cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::string' (aka 'basic_string<char>') to 'TypeDecider<2>::Type' (aka 'unsigned long long') without a conversion operator
```

Which I'm not exactly sure how to go about fixing. And so far my googling-fu has yielded very little. As such, I'm here asking for help before I go to the awful step of writing a Python script in order to write the C++ script.

Comment: Can you show a working example of how you load variables with different types/names?

Comment: The question is written such that it's hard to understand what works and what doesn't. What you have obviously does not work, because you have fixed you type decider to point to `unsigned long long` and try to create it from a string. Dropping your magic it's like writing `int l = (int)std:string("1337");` It's pretty obvious it doesn't work, since there is no built in lexical casting in c++. That's what the compiler is complaining about, but I don't think it's your real problem.

Comment: If you want to parse float or long type from string you should use either something like boost::lexical_cast or string_stream: std::ostringstream strs;
strs << value;
std::string str = strs.str();

Comment: I recommend you get simple classes working (if you can) then come back to templates. Note that all your template instances will have to already exist in the compiled code - you can't invent template argument instantiations at runtime..